# network lag issues on multiplayer games

Tags: networking, defragment, lag

I need help with a networking issue. About 80% of my games are unplayable multiplayer due to lag. One particular game I play (Rocket League on PS4) I get the red network disconnect triangle, even during replays and every game is a series of giant laggy jumps.

My ping is usually 30ms or less (and when other players are low too)
PS4 reports 50mbps download and 5mbps upload speed
I have tried various MTU values in case it's fragmentation
I have tried wired and wireless
I have tried multiple PS4s

Yet for traffic not requiring multiplayer traffic everything is fine, e.g. I can stream Netflix perfectly fine from 2 machines while youtube is being watched and other network traffic is going on.

But I get this fault even when there is no traffic at all.

I've ran various network analysis things with my provider and they say nothing is wrong.

It's not just the PS4, but the PC too.

I have BT Infinity broadband (latest version 5 hub, and have tried a different hub too).

Comment: If you are able to replicate this issue easily enough on the PC, you should download and install [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/#download) and run a traffic capture whilst in game and experiencing high latency. Upload it somewhere and I can take a look over it.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed!

they changed the master socket (the one where you plug your telephone and router into) to a brand new one and now everything is perfect.